# Getting the text from p tag in a div with BeautifulSoup python

Tags: python

i am trying to get the text inside the *p* tag in *div* tag but i cant do this as well!!

**text that i want to get =** هیچ برنامه فروشی متناسب با درخواست شما موجود نمیباشد

link = https://esale.ikco.ir/#!/searchcars?cca=0&csb=1&ccc=0&cpd=0&clt=1

my code is :

```
def main():
    r = requests.post('https://esale.ikco.ir/#!/searchcars?cca=0&csb=1&ccc=0&cpd=0&clt=1', headers=headers,
                      params=params, cookies=cookies)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        print("site is up")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    mytext = soup.find_all('div',id='noItemFound')
    print(mytext)
```

after i run this code, the output is :

```
site is up
[]
```

**can anyone help me to fix this problem?**

Edit : Part of HTML Code

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="full-width">
                            <div id="listOfCar" data-aria="true" class="content-wrap">
                                <div name="resultMessage"></div>
                                <div id="carContainer" class="row car_listings">
                                    <p id="noItemFound" style="display: block;" class="alert alert-danger">هیچ برنامه فروشی متناسب با درخواست شما موجود نمیباشد</p>
                                    <p id="searchError" style="display:none" class="alert alert-danger">در بارگزاري برنامه فروش مشكلي پيش آمده است لطفا مجددا سعي نماييد</p>
                                    <p id="searchErrorLogin" style="display:none" class="alert alert-danger">زمان اعتبار حساب شما به پايان رسيده لطفا از طريق  <a href="#!/Login?t=0"> اين لينك </a> مجددا وارد سيستم شويد"</p>

                                    <!-- ngRepeat: searchCar in vm.Cars -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

i am looking for this :

```
<p id="noItemFound" style="display: block;" class="alert alert-danger">هیچ برنامه فروشی متناسب با درخواست شما موجود نمیباشد</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way you're searching for the `div`. Also, you don't need `find_all`, as the `id` is unique. Try this

```
mytext = soup.find('p',{'id':'noItemFound'})
print(mytext.text)
#هیچ برنامه فروشی متناسب با درخواست شما موجود نمیباشد
```

EDIT:
It appears the data you are trying to scrape is loaded with javascript. You will need a headless browser to scrape your data. Have a look at [Selenium for Python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
how can i determine the exact `div` i am looking for it and change the way of searching for `div`? can you explain please?

unfortunately the code you have written doesn't worked for me , it just returns `None`.

Comment: Could you add the piece of the source html that you want to extract in your answer?

Comment: Sure, Please check my post again

Comment: Thanks, see my edit. You are actually looking for a `p`, rather than a `div`.

Comment: your welcome!
when i run your code, i got this error :
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`
what is the problem?

Comment: It works when I use the html code you have provided. Could you check whether your p tag is actually stored within your soup?

Comment: if i put the HTML code in a variable and run the program it returns the correct output but when i want to find it online in a webpage, the program returns this error : `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`
code is :
    `soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlcode, 'html.parser')
    mytext = soup.find('p', {'id': 'noItemFound'})
    print(mytext.text)`

variable (htmlcode) holds HTML code

Comment: Yes, so I guess the data you are looking for is not in the source HTML, but loaded with javascript. Could you check whether your data of interest is found here `view-source:https://esale.ikco.ir/#!/searchcars?cca=0&csb=1&ccc=0&cpd=0&clt=1`

Comment: Oops! my bad.... i am so sorry!
i can not find it in view-source:[link](https://esale.ikco.ir/#!/searchcars?cca=0&csb=1&ccc=0&cpd=0&clt=1).

you are right :)
the data i want to find loaded with javascript.
then, what is the way to find the data when load with javascript?

Comment: You will need a headless browser to load the javascript. You can have a look at `selenium`. See https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html to get started.